# Error connecting Java to SQL Anywhere database

Tags: java, database, sybase

I am trying to connect a java program to a database. I have sajdbc4.jar in the build path and it worked before, but now I keep getting this error when I try to make the connection:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no dbjdbc12 in java.library.path
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
>       at sybase.jdbc4.sqlanywhere.IDriver.try_load(IDriver.java:455)
>       at sybase.jdbc4.sqlanywhere.IDriver.(IDriver.java:396)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(Unknown Source)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.loadInitialDrivers(Unknown Source)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.(Unknown Source)
>       at Main.main(Main.java:26)

Can someome please help me? Can't find anything abount this issue online.

Comment: Looks like you are missing a native library (`.dll` on Windows, `.so` on Linux) - does that help with anything?

Comment: `sajdbc4.jar` is not a pure Java driver and requires the `dbjdbc12.dll` - just as the error message says. See item 5) here: http://scn.sap.com/community/sql-anywhere/blog/2014/05/02/connecting-to-sql-anywhere-using-jdbc

Answer (score 3):

For windows find this file in your computer:

```
dbjdbc12.dll
```

For linux find this file:

```
libdbjdbc12.so
```

Put the location of this file on the java.library.path either with a command line option:

```
java -Djava.library.path=DIRECTORYWITHDLL ...
```

or  using System.setProperty in your code:

```
System.setProperty("java.library.path","DIRECTORYWITHDLL");
```

Answer (score 0):

For Linux, you need to add the dbjdbc12.so to java.library.path using:

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/some/path/that/contain/dbjdbc12.so

this is the same for dbjdbc16 also.
Since, sybase.jdbc4 driver need this file. Please refer- [https://blogs.sap.com/2014/05/02/connecting-to-sql-anywhere-using-jdbc-2/#:~:text=jar%20is%20in%20the%20classpath,Connection%20con%20%3D%20DriverManager](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/05/02/connecting-to-sql-anywhere-using-jdbc-2/#:%7E:text=jar%20is%20in%20the%20classpath,Connection%20con%20%3D%20DriverManager).

Similarly, for windows add dbjdbc12.dll file.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Anywhere 17 `libdbjdbc17.so` was not suffiecient, it was then complaning about the next file:

```
failed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/local/tomcat/native-jni-lib/libdbjdbc17.so: libdbtasks17_r.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So I ended up adding all files from the `lib64` folder from the [Database client](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/SQLANY/SAP+SQL+Anywhere+Database+Client+Download) (after I installed it on some other linux machine) to my tomcat lib path and it worked.